# Using DECLARE while creating a VIEW?

Tags: sql-server

The literature says that the `declare` statement is not compatible with creating a View. How do I get around it?

My `declare` statement looks like:

```
DECLARE @risk_5 TABLE (Code VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @risk_5 (Code) VALUES ('AA'),('BB'),('CC');
```

and is then used within a select statement:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE 
       WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code from @risk_5)
          THEN '3'  
    END AS Risk_Country5
FROM x
```

The recommendation is to pack the `declare` into a CTE or a stored procedure.
With both these recommendations though, I do not understand how to connect the two? What am I missing?

Comment: You can't do anything like that in a view... you have 2 options, replace the variables with the literal values, or use a table valued function.

Comment: A view is essentially just a reusable query... nothing more.

Comment: Yeah, I need the view for full automation and output into a a visualisation software. Unfortunately, the stuff I need to declare comes from an xls output that currently has to be manually uploaded. Not idle

Comment: You can select from a table valued function just as easy as a view AND you can use variables in a TVF.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use variable try to use stored procedures, if you write a select query in the stored procedure you can get the data too. And you can use declare inside.
I use this way in my solution e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLoadSiteMass]( @month INT, 
                           @year int,
                           @storageId int,
                           @parent nvarchar(50),
                           @materialSourceId nvarchar(100),
                           @complexIds nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @MonthPrev int
DECLARE @YearPrev int
SET @MonthPrev = CASE WHEN @Month = 1 THEN 12 ELSE @Month - 1 END
SET @YearPrev = CASE WHEN @Month = 1 THEN @Year - 1 ELSE @Year END
declare  @WagonLoadSiteId int
set @WagonLoadSiteId = (select top 1 CarriageLoadSiteId from CarriageLoadSite where LoadSiteType = 2);


DECLARE @loadSide nvarchar(10), @result decimal(18,3)
SET @loadSide=cast( @storageId as nvarchar(50));

WITH CarriageLoadSiteTreeView (
[CarriageLoadSiteId],RootId,RootName,[Code], Name, ParentID, [LoadSiteType],IsDelete, 
CodeSAP,DepartmentId, Capacity, MinLimit, MaxLimit,  LoadSitePlaceTypeId) AS
(
    SELECT  [CarriageLoadSiteId],
            [CarriageLoadSiteId] RootId,
            Name RootName,
            [Code], 
            Name, 
            ParentID, 
            [LoadSiteType],
            [IsDelete],
            CodeSAP,
            DepartmentId, 
            Capacity, 
            MinLimit, 
            MaxLimit,
            LoadSitePlaceTypeId
    FROM CarriageLoadSite WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE ISNULL(ParentID,0) =isnull(@storageId,0)  AND Isdelete!=1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT d.[CarriageLoadSiteId],
           q.RootId RootId,
           RootName RootName,
           d.[Code], 
           d.Name, 
           d.ParentID, 
           d.[LoadSiteType], 
           d.[IsDelete], 
           d.CodeSAP,
           d.DepartmentId, 
           d.Capacity, 
           d.MinLimit, 
           d.MaxLimit,
           d.LoadSitePlaceTypeId
    FROM CarriageLoadSite AS d WITH(NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN CarriageLoadSiteTreeView AS q  ON d.ParentID = q.[CarriageLoadSiteId] WHERE  d.IsDelete!=1
)

         
SELECT 
        ComplexId, 
        RootId Id, 
        cast(RootId as nvarchar(8))+'|Sclad'+IIF(RootId=max(R.CarriageLoadSiteId),'|finish','') [Uid],
        RootName CarriageLoadSiteName,
        ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT-movement-consumption)/1000,3) Amount, 
        cast(1 as bit) hasChildren,
        T.FullPathId Path,
        UparentId=IIF(@parent is null,'',@parent),
        [Type]=0,
        Petal = IIF(RootId=max(R.CarriageLoadSiteId),'|Sclad|finish','') 

FROM (
         SELECT 
                 RootId
                ,RootName
                ,t.CarriageLoadSiteId
                ,t.MaterialId
                ,YEAR(t.Period) [Year]
                ,MONTH(t.Period) [Month]
                ,round( case when (t.Amount=0 or t.Amount is null) and (tt.Type=0 or  [TypeAmountCarriage]=1 )then carr.[CertifNetto]else t.Amount  end ,0 )[Amount]
                ,t.UnitId
                , CarriageId
                , tt.TurnoverTypeId
                ,round(dbo.GetMovementByTurnOverWithTempValue(t.turnoverid),5) movement
                ,dbo.GetConsumptionByTurnOver(t.turnoverid) consumption
                ,0 stockBegin
                ,round(t.Amount,0 ) CommingAmount
                ,case when (t.Amount=0 or t.Amount is null) and tt.Type=0 then 1 else 0  end  [IsNotConfirmed]
                ,[TypeAmountCarriage]
                ,M.ComplexId
        
        FROM              Turnover t WITH(NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN TurnoverType tt ON tt.TurnoverTypeId = t.TurnoverTypeId
                INNER JOIN CarriageLoadSiteTreeView l ON l.CarriageLoadSiteId = t.CarriageLoadSiteId
                INNER JOIN [Carriages] carr on carr.[CarriagesID]=t.[CarriageId]
                INNER JOIN Material M on M.MaterialID=t.MaterialId

        WHERE   YEAR(t.Period) = @Year AND 
        MONTH(t.Period) = @Month AND 
        l.LoadSiteType = 0 AND 
        tt.type in (0,5,4)  AND 
        isclear=0 AND 
        M.MaterialSourceID in (select value from string_split(@materialSourceId, ','))      
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT   RootId
                ,RootName
                ,s.CarriageLoadSiteId
                ,s.MaterialId
                ,@Year [Year]
                ,@Month [Month]
                ,round(s.Amount,0)
                ,s.UnitId
                ,CarriageId
                ,[TurnoverTypeId]
                ,round(dbo.GetMovementByStock(s.StockId),5) movement
                ,dbo.GetConsumptionByStock(s.StockId) consumption
                ,round(s.Amount,0)-s.spendStock
                ,0
                ,0 [IsNotConfirmed]
                ,[TypeAmountCarriage]
                ,M.ComplexId
        FROM Stock s
                INNER JOIN CarriageLoadSiteTreeView l ON l.CarriageLoadSiteId = s.CarriageLoadSiteId
                INNER JOIN Material M on M.MaterialID=s.MaterialId
        WHERE   s.[Year] = @YearPrev  AND
                s.[Month] = @MonthPrev AND
                s.[Type] = 0 AND
                l.LoadSiteType = 0 AND
                amount >0 AND
                isclear=0 AND
                M.MaterialSourceID in (select value from string_split(@materialSourceId, ','))      

        
        ) as R 
        INNER JOIN CariageLoadSiteTree T on T.CarriageLoadSiteId=RootId
        INNER JOIN string_split(@complexIds, ',') MM ON CAST(MM.value AS int) = R.ComplexId
        WHERE  AMOUNT-movement-consumption>10
        
        GROUP BY RootName,RootId,ComplexId, T.FullPathId
        ORDER BY RootName
```